# cmake of "libarchive" fails on OSX Maverick

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I'm trying to compile libarchive using `cmake -G Xcode libarchive` according to the [official build instructions](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/BuildInstructions#wiki-MacOSXcode)

I ve cmake 2.8.12 installed via mac port and use the current [CMakeList.txt](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

`cmake -G Xcode libarchive` outputs

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:177 (SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:193 (INSTALL_MAN):
  Unknown CMake command "INSTALL_MAN".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure from the top-level directory (the one containing the README file):

$ cmake -G Xcode .

the subsidiary CMakeLists.txt files in various directories are not complete and cannot be used by themselves.